# Spark SQL real time on Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I'm actually asking my self about performance of using Spark SQL with Hive to do real time analytics.
I know that Hive has been created for batch processing, and Spark is use to do fast queries.

But, use Spark SQL with Hive will allow me to do real time queries ? Or it just will make fastest queries but not real time.
Should I use an other datawarehouse instead of Hive, like Hbase ?

Thanks in advance,
Florian

Comment: Hive and HBase are pretty apples-and-oranges, so you probably need to clarify what you need to do. If you're looking for something that works in 'real-time' in the sense of concurrent access to normal-scale MySQL, no, Hive/Spark would not be close.

Comment: I need to provide dashboard for my customers, with data information about there sells. So when they want to access to there dashboard, the result of my queries must be very fast. With what you said, I need to understand that using Hive and Spark isn't what I need in my use case, is that right ? I should probably look at an issue like MemSQL ?

Comment: Well in the Hadoop ecosystem it's probably stuff like Impala. If you don't have quite big data, you don't need Hadoop & co. at all.

Answer (score 1):

While Spark can be much faster than hive, its still probably not an ideal solution for say serving a website. So if Spark SQL can do "realtime" queries or not depends largely on what sort of timelines you consider realtime, if your dataset is small enough to cache in memory, and if your queries are able to take advantage of partitioning.

Comment: Okey, I need to provide the result of my queries on a website, so when I say "realtime", it must be acceptable for a website. Use Hbase could be a better alternative than hive ?

Comment: How large is your data? What sort of queries do you need to serve (e.g. do you need joins)? Some options would be trying to cache the data in Spark (remember this can be across many nodes), or using a traditional database (with shading).

Comment: My data is growing maximum of 1 TB per year, and I need to make joins. With growing data like that, I think a traditionnal database isn't the best solution, it's because of that I'm searching a "Big Data" issue. I want to use ZoomData too, so I'm looking for a compatible technology.

Comment: Not for sure 100% as I don't know the data but with 1TB/Year you can do it it's not a lot of data and with some thinking what to load in memory you can do it. I've the same problem as you but with 1Tb by Day !!!